# Accessing iPhone Notification

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, apple-push-notifications

I am developing an iPhone app and am using push notification to create a chatting capability in my app. When the app receives the notification, the message is then stored in an SQLite database from which the message view is populated. My problem is sometimes the phone receives the notification while the application is not running but when the app starts by not clicking the notification (or when there are more than one notification), I just don't have a way of processing those notifications. What I'll like to do is when the app launch, I check for all local and push notifications, process and clear them from the apple notification app. I hope my question is clear enough. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no API for access to notification information on iOS. The only way to get notification info into your app is *if* the user activates your app from the notification.

For this reason, chat apps on iOS, like AIM, Textie, ect., check their servers for new messages when they're activated. I suspect you'll have to do the same.

If the user activates your app from a notification, you can still use that information to go to the correct conversation, but the content of the that conversation should be populated from the server.

Also, the only way to programatically "clear" notifications is to set the the app's badge count to zero.